# how (and where) to store child objects from UI (jqgrid) to asp.net-mvc server, before saving parent object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, jqgrid, parent-child

I have an asp.net- mvc site and I use nhibernate.  I am running into an issue where my UI needs to add child items to a parent object but that parent object has yet to be inserted (and thus doesn't have an ID)

Here are the details:

I have a basic "detail" page that is a form (a bunch of input controls) that represent the properties of an object (a **Project** object in this case) where a have a textbox for Name, textarea for description, etc . .

A (simplified view) **Project** object looks like this

```
public class Project
{
      public string Name;
      public string Description;
      public List<Project> Dependencies;
      public int Id;
}
```

i reuse this screen for adding a new **Project** (where all the controls are blank on startup
i reuse this screen for editing existing **Project** (where i load all of controls from the server given a project Id)

the issue is now around the UI of adding and removing **Dependencies** items to the Dependency property of a **Project** (a list).  Its a little complicated but I cant just use a regular multiselect listbox because there needs to be a search for a dependency (as there are thousands of them)

The UI that i decided to use to show the list of dependencies is a jqGrid.

[image]

When you click on the Add button of the jqgrid, it pops up a little dialog to add a dependency

[image]

when you choose a project, it then calls the server to add a dependency to the project, close the popup and then refresh the "Dependency grid" to show you the latest list of dependency projects.

Here is my add dependency code:

```
public ActionResult AddDepedency(Dependency dependency)
{
      var project = GetProjectFromRepository(dependency.ProjectId);
      var projectDependency = GetProjectFromRepository(dependency.DependencyProjectId);

      project.Dependencies.Add(projectDependency);
      this.Repository.Save(project);
      this.Repository.Commit();
}
```

by the way for reference, here is the relationship in my ProjectMap class for fluent nhibernate wiring:

```
  HasMany(x => x.Dependencies).AsBag().Inverse().Cascase.AllDeleteOrphan().Fetch.Select().BatchSize(80);
```

This works fine when i am doing this for the edit screen AS I ALREADY HAVE A PROJECT ID.

but i can't figure out how to get this to work on the ADD project screen because people would be trying to add a dependency to a project BEFORE the initial project itself is saved so it **doesn't yet have an id**.

should i use some session cache to temporarily store this list? so when i actually go to commit the project for insert, at that point i them attach all of the dependencies at that time to the main project after the project insert succeeds ?

one option, is that I could simply not support adding dependencies on the ADD project page and only support it on the EDIT project page but that seems like it will be annoying to the users.

Has anyone run into this issue before and could offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would store the new dependencies into HTML input fields and only when the user submits the form send them all to the server which will insert them into the database. Here's a [nice blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) illustrating the concept.